# How to make a class for button widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

I am going to have a bunch of buttons in my flutter app, and I want to make a class for it so I don't need to copy-paste it and make my code look long for the same type of code. I make the class, no problem there but I am struggling because I want every button to go to a different page when pressed. How to achieve this?

```html
class thebuttonmaka extends StatelessWidget {
  final String texxt;
  final String buum;
  const thebuttonmaka(this.texxt);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 5,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        child: MaterialButton(
          minWidth: 250,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          onPressed: WHAT TO PUT HERE?,
          child: Text(texxt,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I basically need help where I put what to put here. I want to add this option to constructor so whenever I call the class I can put where the button navigates to. Example
thebuttonmaka('signup',signuppage)

Comment: Just a style thing... class names are recommended to begin with an uppercase letter: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-types-using-uppercamelcase

Comment: I don't use capitalized letters with classes.

Comment: Why fight the style guide?

Comment: Thats how I code and will code bud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class thebuttonmaka extends StatelessWidget {
  final String texxt;
  final String buum;
  final Function function; // add this
  const thebuttonmaka(this.texxt, this.function, this.buum); // change this

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 5,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        child: MaterialButton(
          minWidth: 250,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          onPressed: function, // add this here
          child: Text(texxt,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use it like

```
thebuttonmaka('signup',signuppage)
```

Comment: To the downvoter, please let me know the reason of downvoting this answer, thank you.

Comment: Well I dont know who did that but your answer is right. IAppreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
class thebuttonmaka extends StatelessWidget {
  final String texxt;
  final String buum;
  final Function()? onPressed;
  const thebuttonmaka(this.texxt, this.onPressed, this.buum); // change this

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 5,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        child: MaterialButton(
          minWidth: 250,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          onPressed: onPressed, // add this here
          child: Text(texxt,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can call the function like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child:thebuttonmaka(
              'texxt',
                  (){
                print('thebuttonmaka pressed');
                },
              'buum'),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define your class like this and customize literally everything about your button (you can pass textalignment and style as well, I am just showing an example) -

```
class CommonButton {
      static MaterialButton myButton(BuildContext context, int width, int l, int t, int r, int b, func, String text) {
        return MaterialButton(
              minWidth: width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(l, t, r, b),
              onPressed: func,
              child: Text(text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
                      .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            );
      }
     }
```

When you want to use this somewhere, just call it like this -

```
CommonButton.myButton(...)
```

(You have to obviously pass the `onPressed` function as well)